# Maya: Defer a script until after VRay is registered?

Tags: python, maya

I'm trying to delay a part of my pipeline tool (which runs during the startup of Maya) to run after VRay has been registered.

I'm currently delaying the initialization of the tool in a userSetup.py like so:

```
def run_my_tool():
    import my_tool
    reload(my_tool)

mc.evalDeferred("run_my_tool()")
```

I've tried using evalDeferred within the tool to delay the execution of the render_settings script, but it keeps running before VRay has been registered.  Any thoughts on how to create a listener for the VRay register event, or what event that is? Thanks!

**EDIT**:

Made a new topic to figure out how to correctly use theodox's condition/scriptJob commands suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39252664/maya-python-running-condition-command-and-scriptjob-command-from-within-a-mod).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uiron over at tech-artists.com showed me how to do this properly.  Here's a [link to the thread](http://tech-artists.org/forum/showthread.php?3203-need-help-passing-second-argument-to-event-for-scriptJob-in-maya)

Here's the post by uiron:

"don't pass the python code as string unless you have to. Wherever a python callback is accepted (that's not everywhere in Maya's api, but mostly everywhere), try one of these:

```
# notice that we're passing a function, not function call
mc.scriptJob(runOnce=True, e=["idle", myObject.myMethod], permanent=True)
mc.scriptJob(runOnce=True, e=["idle", myGlobalFunction], permanent=True)

# when in doubt, wrap into temporary function; remember that in Python you can 
# declare functions anywhere in the code, even inside other functions
open_file_path = '...'
def idle_handler(*args):
   # here's where you solve the 'how to pass the argument into the handler' problem - 
   # use variable from outer scope
   file_manip_open_fn(open_file_path)
mc.scriptJob(runOnce=True, e=["idle", idle_handler], permanent=True)
```

"

Comment: That's a fairly common way to defer until all loads are done.  You can also create a custom condition which checks for the plugin and fires when it's loading using the `condition` command and a `scriptJob(ct=True)`

Comment: That sounds great, I'll give that a shot too, thanks!

Comment: @theodox I'm trying out your suggestion, but I'm running into problems when running my condition script from a module. It works fine when I run it from the script editor.  I've posted the code in my original post under EDIT