# Maya (Python): Running condition command and scriptJob command from within a module

Tags: python, conditional-statements, maya

I'm creating a UI tool that loads during Maya's startup, and executes some modules AFTER VRay has initialized (otherwise an error is thrown).

A suggestion from my broader question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38601706/maya-defer-a-script-until-after-vray-is-registered) has lead me to try out the condition and scriptJob commands.

The listener.py code below works when run from within Maya's script editor, but when I import the listener module and run it using the launcher.py code, I get this error:

```
Error: line 1: name 'is_vray_loaded' is not defined
Traceback: (most recent call last):
    File "<maya console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'is_vray_loaded' is not defined
```

**Note** that the condition command requires a mel command syntax (seems to be a bug), so just calling the normal function doesn't work and gives an error that procedure cannot be found).

Here's the listener:

```
# vray_listener.py

import os

import maya.cmds as mc
import maya.mel as mel

vray_plugin_path_2016   = os.path.join('C:', os.sep, 'Program Files', 'Autodesk', 'Maya2016', 'vray', 'plug-ins', 'vrayformaya.mll')

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
def is_vray_loaded():
    return mc.pluginInfo(vray_plugin_path_2016, q=1, l=True)

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
def hey():
    print 'hey'

mc.condition('vray_initialized', initialize=True, d='idle', s='python("is_vray_loaded()");')

mc.scriptJob(ct=['vray_initialized', 'hey()'])
```

Here's the launcher:

```
# launcher.py

import sys

vray_listener_path = 'S:/path/to/module'

if vray_listener_path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(vray_listener_path)

import vray_listener
reload(vray_listener)
```

Answer (score 1):

try that,

```
import os
import maya.cmds as mc
import maya.mel as mel

vray_plugin_path_2016   = os.path.join('C:', os.sep, 'Program Files', 'Autodesk', 'Maya2016', 'vray', 'plug-ins', 'vrayformaya.mll')

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
def is_vray_loaded(*args):
    return mc.pluginInfo(vray_plugin_path_2016, q=1, l=True)

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
def hey(*args):
    print 'hey'

mc.condition('vray_initialized', initialize=True, d='idle', s=is_vray_loaded)

mc.scriptJob(ct=['vray_initialized', 'hey'])
```

Comment: welcome,please read that, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24616757/maya-python-cmds-button-with-ui-passing-variables-and-calling-a-function

Comment: Thank you for the help and link! I thought it was working, but it looks like there was some variable in the cache that made it seem like it was working. I'm unable to reproduce the working results on a fresh open of Maya.

Comment: let me please know your solution, for the next time......the same error?

Comment: If I just run your code in the script editor I get this error: `// Error: <function is_vray_loaded at 0x0000000047E8B518>; //
// Error: Line 1.1: Syntax error //`

Comment: okay, can you edit the call command again like: 'python("is_vray_loaded()");') but without the () ......eg: mc.condition('vray_initialized', initialize=True, d='idle', s='python("is_vray_loaded");')

Comment: That fixes the syntax error when running from the script editor, but I'm not seeing anything print when I turn on VRay.  Also, when I try to use the launcher script to import the module and run it, I'm getting the same errors from my initial question.

Comment: can you import the  "is_vray_loaded" func with  import vray_listener
reload(vray_listener); vray_listener.is_vray_loaded()?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122330/discussion-between-mike-bourbeau-and-ari-gold).